# Google Search Console is not indexing my next.js Links to blog articles

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-search-console

I have a next.js website that has a blog. The blog has a home page that consists of links to all my blog posts that get fetched from my backend. Here is the component for the page:

```
import { APIURL } from './../../constants'
import services from './../../components/services'
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

class Blog extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blog_posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const response = await services.get_v2(APIURL.GET_BLOG_POSTS, {params: {}})
    if (response) {
      const blog_posts = []
      for (const post in response) {
        const blog_post = response[post]
        const blog_image = blog_post['image'] ? blog_post['image'] : '/no-image.png'
        const title_without_spaces = blog_post['title'].replace(new RegExp("\\ ","g"),'-')
        blog_posts.push(
          <Link key={'blog-post-' + post}
                href={{
                  pathname: '/blog/[title]',
                  query: { title: title_without_spaces },
                }}>
            <a className="blog-card">
              <div className="blog-title">{blog_post['title']}</div>
              <div className="blog-created">{blog_post['created_at']}</div>
            </a>
          </Link>

        )
      }
      this.setState({blog_posts: blog_posts})
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="home-container">
          <h1 className='blog-index-title'>
            Blog
          </h1>
          <div className="blog-index">
              {this.state.blog_posts}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Blog
```

I'd expect each blog individual blog post to get crawled and indexed by google because I am using the next.js Link component. However that is not the case. This blog home page is also getting indexed correctly so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong at this point. What do I need to do in order to get google to crawl and index these individual blog post links? Is there something I can add to the sitemap to index all pages from the blog? For example:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.io/blog/*</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
```

***UPDATE***

Code now looks like this but blog pages are still not indexed:

```
export default function Blog({ data }) {
  data = JSON.parse(data)
  let blog_posts = []
  if (data) {
    for (const post in data) {
      const blog_post = data[post]
      const title_without_spaces = blog_post['title'].replace(new RegExp("\\ ","g"),'-')
      blog_posts.push(
        <Link key={'blog-post-' + post}
              href={{
                pathname: '/blog/[title]',
                query: { title: title_without_spaces },
              }}>
          <a className="blog-card">
            <div className="blog-title">{blog_post['title']}</div>
            <div className="blog-created">{blog_post['created_at']}</div>
          </a>
        </Link>

      )
    }
  }
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="home-container">
          <h1 className='blog-index-title'>
           Blog
          </h1>
          <div className="blog-index">
              {blog_posts}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await services.get_v2(APIURL.GET_BLOG_POSTS, {params: {}})
  const data = JSON.stringify(response)
  return { props: { data } }
}
```

Comment: Crawlers aren't seeing the links because you're only rendering them on the client-side (`componentDidMount` only runs on the browser). Fetch the data on the server with [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)/[`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering.

Comment: I'm now using `getServerSideProps` to retrieve the the blog data then creating the links in the hook based on that data and the pages are still not being indexed. (see updated)

Answer (score 0):

if you using cloudflare try turn developer and test again. If your test is pass you need turn off some feature in cloudflare like rocketload

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not using cloudflare